# how do i fix this .cls file problem

Tags: document-classes, cls

Im trying to write a .cls file but im gettin a few problems:

.cls file:

```
\def\autor#1{\def\@autor{#1}}
\def\email#1{\def\@email{#1}}
\def\universidade#1{\def\@universidade{#1}}
\newcommand{\cabecalho}{%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    {\Large\noindent \@titulo} \\
    \vspace{0.1cm}

    {\large\noindent\@autor} \\
    {\@universidade} \\
    {\textit{email: }\@email}\\
    {\@universidade} \\
    {\textit{email: }\@email}
\end{minipage}}
```

.tex file:

```
\autor{author 1$^1$ e author 2$^2$}
\email{email 1}
\universidade{$^1$university 1} 
\email{email 2}
\universidade{$^2$university 2}
```

and the output is:

[image]

Its only using the last university and email given, how can i fix this?

Comment: The second argument overwrites the first one. Maybe you can use the `authblk` package?

Comment: I agree with @Stephen, you may not want to reinvent the wheel. Alternatively if you do want to reinvent the wheel,  you may want to consider this as an opportunity to learn the expl3 syntax, which makes writing packages much easier (once you get used to it). See [How to use loop for creating defined number of newcommands counting authors](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/688000) for an example similar to what you're doing.